# UPS LTL Freight Rate Quote XML

Tags: xml, ups

I looked everywhere and I'm sure it must be out there but I'm looking for the XML request that would be posted to UPS to retrieve a rate quote. FOR LTL.

For some reason I cannot find it. Could someone please help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you download the ShipAPI documentation @ ups.com there is information on ground freight via web services.

https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit

Comment: Do you mean the Shipping.zip file? Because I am also wanting to know how to get a Ground Freight Rate, but this Shipping.zip file is not it. Could you please be more specific as to what on the Developer site you're referring to?